# 'l2' not defined as regularizer

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=10, input_shape=[784], activation='sigmoid', kernal_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-23-76c00e884f10> in <module>()
      7 
      8 model = Sequential()
----> 9 model.add(Dense(units=10, input_shape=[784], activation='sigmoid', kernal_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
     10 model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     11 model.summary()

NameError: name 'l2' is not defined
```

What is going on? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The error is clear. You haven't defined `l2` function. Try it like this: `kernal_regularizer=regularizers.L2(0.01)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
kernal_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0, l2=0.01)
```

instead of `kernal_regularizer=l2(0.01)`

Link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/l1_l2